# Best Way to Get the View's Great Great Grand Parent View?

Tags: android, view, parent, android-databinding

I need to obtain a reference to the great great grandparent's view. Currently I am doing it successfully using the following code:

```
FabToolbar fabToolbar = (FabToolbar) view.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();
```

This seems somewhat ridiculous, or, is it just the way it's done?

The reason I did it this way was due to my preference to want to use data binding in my layout, and my inability to obtain a reference to any view but the view being clicked. This is given the following code you will see below, ex:

```
@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickPart(view)}
```

The view being passed into the method is the MaterialIconView, this appears to be the only view I can reference, or is there a way to pass additional parameters to this method? My full layout is as below, please keep in mind that FabToolbar contains a LinearLayout child and a RelativeLayout child, hence why you see four calls to getParent() and not two (looking at the layout below).

```
<com.bowyer.app.fabtoolbar.FabToolbar
            android:id="@+id/fab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tb_anim_duration="400"
            app:tb_color="@color/primary"
            app:tb_container_gravity="center"
            app:tb_fab_type="normal">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/accent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_part"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickPart(view)}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="engine"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_dyno"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickDyno(view)}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="chart_line"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_timeslip"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickTimeslip(view)}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="timer_10"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_laptime"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickLaptime(view)}"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="timer"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_fuel"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickFuel(view)}"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="gas_station"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />

            <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_repair"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickRepair(view)}"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/content_space"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    app:materialIcon="wrench"
                    app:materialIconColor="#fff"
                    app:materialIconSize="24dp"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

    </com.bowyer.app.fabtoolbar.FabToolbar>
```

Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Hey - I have added an answer shortly after the first one. Have you already read it? It is possible to pass a view in the onclick listener. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass other `Views` from your layout with `DataBinding`:

```
<com.bowyer.app.fabtoolbar.FabToolbar
        android:id="@+id/fab_toolbar">

    <LinearLayout>

        <net.steamcrafted.materialiconlib.MaterialIconView
                android:id="@+id/ic_part"
                android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewModel.onClickPart(view, fabToolbar)}"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.bowyer.app.fabtoolbar.FabToolbar>
```

In your `ViewModel`:

```
public void onClickPart(View view, FabToolbar fabToolbar){ ... }
```

You need to use the camel case writing for any referenced view in data binding.

You can also pass properties of a view like that. (for example `Visibility`, `isChecked`, ... )

[Here](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-lets-flip-this-thing-dc17792d6c24#.z9zznc5nn) is an article from George Mount where he uses this (under "View attributes"). (Only for other properties, but I think you'll get the idea)

Comment: Thank you so much! I would like to learn more about the syntax used for data binding. Could you please explain what this syntax is called, that is the @{(view) -> viewModel.onClickPart(view, fabToolbar)}? It looks like Vulcan at this point, but I'm sure it's logical.

Comment: I think it's called 'Lambda expression', [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-the-big-event-2697089dd0d7#.g2gdldymd) is another article from George Mount (he and Yigit designed the Data Binding library), where he explains the Click Events :) I'm glad I could help you!

Comment: Thank you @Amylinn